# VPN tunnel not coming up in sonicwall firewall 3500 NSA

Tags: vpn, sonicwall

I have a customer who has two internet connection at two location of his office via my ISP and another ISP.

THe problem is when this customer uses other ISP conenction at both ends of and makes a VPN tunnel, its coming up and working.

When he uses my ISP at one site and other ISP at other one, the tunnel works also vice versa too.

BUt when he uses my ISP connection at both the ends the tunnel is not coming up :(

Customer is using Sonicwall firewall NSA 250M , NSA 3500

I m using : Cisco 4948 Switch where both end traffic is coming via vlan and then from my switch its going to Edge router for internet.

I tested end-2-end link before firewall via file sharing , its working fine.
I used Cisco 1900 Rouer nd tested via ISPEC tunnel , its working fine.

Not seeing any issue in my network but unable to solve this issue .

CAn someone guide me pls .